# How to install pySerial on Windows XP

Tags: python, windows, windows-xp, pyserial

How can I install pySerial on an XP machine that works with the XP compatable version of Python3?

PS. This is my first stackoverflow post. :)

Comment: Try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial/2.7

Comment: FYI:  Python 3.4 is the last Windows XP compatible Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get PySerial on Windows XP:

1.) The latest versions of pySerial will not work on XP. You need to [download pySerial 3.0.1](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/releases/tag/v3.0.1) or older. I downloaded the exe.

2.) This exe is not a usual install file. If you try to double click it you will get the Windows error: "pySerial3.0.1.exe is not a valid Win32 application."

To install this exe you need to have python installed and then, using command prompt, navigate to the directory that has the pySerial3.0.1.exe in it and run: easy_install pySerial3.0.1.exe

That should install pySerial on your XP machine. This works with the XP compatible version of Python3, (which is [3.4,9](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-349/))

Answer (score 2):

Pyserial 3.0.1 is the last version that is supported on Windows XP

If you have `pip`, just use:

```
pip install pyserial==3.0.1
```

Incidentally the last XP compatible Python 3 is 3.4 (at post time, 3.4.9)
can be found [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-349/)

To my knowledge, Python 2.7 still remains XP compatible (at post time, 2.7.15) can be found [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2715/)